# Modify dynamic info window code to work for image links?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to modify this code example for dynamic info windows to work for images instead of text:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_infowindow_content

I know that I can use this:

```
<a href="{column_name}" target="_blank">text</a>
```

to make the images come up as links that open a new page using the Fusion Table custom InfoWindow UI, but some of the cells in my Fusion Table have an image URL, and others are empty. I want the InfoWindow to leave out the image link if there is no URL in the cell. Since I can't code this using the Fusion Table UI, I was wondering if it is possible to use the Fusion Tables Layer in the Google Maps API and modify this section of code:

```
 // If the delivery == yes, add content to the window
          if (e.row['delivery'].value == 'yes') {
            e.infoWindowHtml += "Delivers!";
          }
```

to test for the image URL instead testing for "yes"?? I would like the InfoWindow to display the link to the image if it is there, and I would like the link to be left out if the cell is empty.

Here is a link to my Fusion Table:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=15wosKAeHC0gcpU_N6UPbxPL09RrEBKlQNEaCmnU#map:id=3

I would like to test all cells in the "y2012" column.

Any ideas??

Comment: `Any ideas??` - write the code to do that.  Can't help without more details about what your table looks like, particularly what the name of the column is.  If it isn't the empty string, add the link to the infowindow.

Comment: I have added the link to my Fusion Table in the post. I am not sure how to write the code to do that, does the information that I added help clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use what we call [dynamic templating](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/3081246?hl=en&ref_topic=2575652) for the info windows. This lets you [Closure Template](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts) syntax in an info window, including exactly your case of leaving out empty fields.

Comment: Thanks the dynamic templates let me do exactly what I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in a click event listener on the layer:

```
 // If the y2012 != "", add open the picture
 if (e.row['y2012'].value != '') {
    window.open(e.row['y2012'].value);
 }
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_QueryPanAndZoomOpenWindow.html)